# Prevent a method from being executed during tests Codeception

Tags: php, laravel-5, codeception

When I execute `codecept run` on my terminal, I get all my tests executed. I would like to suppress one specific method from being executed.

```
Api Tests (6) ---------------------------------------------------------------------
✔ ...Cest: It_should_deny_access_to_anonymous_user (1.112s)
✔ ...Cest: It_should_deny_access_to_unauthorized_user (0.26s)
✔ ...Cest: It_should_deny_access_to_host_without_any_user (0.22s)
✔ ...Cest: It_should_access_firewall_settings_with_authorized_user (0.28s)
✔ ...Cest: Token (0.21s)
✔ ...Cest: It_should_create_new_firewall_setting (0.5s)
```

The method called `Token` actually belongs to a `Trait` that my Test Class uses

```
class FirewallSettingsAuthorizationCest {

    use MakeTokens;

    ...
}
```

How do I block methods in that trait from being executed as a test?

In general, how do I write a method that will not be tested by Codeception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Each public method of Cest (except those starting with _) will be executed as a test"

So to write a method that will not be tested, you could try changing method visibility (if possible) or leading the method name with an underscore (_).

Source: http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage

Comment: Currently, this is the right answer. Unfortunately it does not fit my needs, so I opened an Issue with Codeception at https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3357